# Dojox/app: Is it possible to define views programatically

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.app

Is it possible to code a view programatically instead of using an html template? All the demos I have seen use an html template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.
Add your HTML markup as a string for property `templateString`,
the following code does not use an .html template as for your question.
You can use string concatenation in order to modify your template programatically.

More information on [templateString here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/_TemplatedMixin.html).

Example below is taken from user [Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1850322/ben) from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31162782/how-to-add-a-html-label-before-a-validationtextbox-dynamically) to a my older question:

```js
require(['dijit/_WidgetBase', 'dijit/_TemplatedMixin', 'dojo/_base/declare', 'dojo/domReady!'], function(_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, declare, domReady) {

    //Foo represent any widget with template available in dojo
    //replace by the widget you want to use
    var Foo = declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin], {});

    var foo = new Foo({
      templateString: '<div>This is my teemplate and ${bar}</div>',
      bar: "this is added to the template"
    });

    
    foo.placeAt('layout');

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" media="screen">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<div id="layout"></div>
```

Comment: Hey, this is a pure copy paste of my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31162782/how-to-add-a-html-label-before-a-validationtextbox-dynamically/31163888#31163888

Comment: Note: I don't mind you copied it but you could have cleaned it to only show the templateString part. that would be more relevant

Comment: @ben thanks for writing me back, I apologize I did not want make a plagiarism :) I just forgot to add your credit. I have made an edit. Let me know if fine for you. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: No worry, sharing is the purpose of stackoverflow. Just thought it would be more usefull to only keep the templaceString part for a more meaning full answer :)

Comment: @ben thanks ben, I have added a comment the code highlighting templateString. thanks for sharing :)

Comment: I am not sure if this is what I am looking for. In the config file dojox/app uses there is something like this:
`"views": {
        "list": {
            "controller": "contactsList/views/list",
            "template": "contactsList/views/list.html"
        }
    }`


I want to create the view completely in code with no html. Can I include that in the controller and then just not include the template tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use placeholder's in your HTML template having defined basic tag structure in template and providing value's to the placeholder from JS side.

Ex:

```
<div>

<div data-dojo-type="dojox.layout.contentpane" >
{content}
</div>

</div>
```

OR

You may  also modify some HTML template dynamically from "postMixInProperties()"

Refer to Widget Life cycle to get some info on that 
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/_WidgetBase.html